# Mark cards that are in progress for two long on Kanban board in Youtrack

Tags: youtrack

We're using a Kanban board in our team. Cards have a "state" which goes from planned to "in progress" and then in review.

I'm trying to see if there is a way to highlight any issue that has been in progress for more than a few days, but haven't found anything so far.

"Highlight" is used liberally here. It can be via a color, bold, or anything that makes it clear for the next standup that those issues should be discussed further.

Any pointers appreciated.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can [create a workflow](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/cloud/on-schedule-rules.html#sample-on-schedule-rule) that will automatically assign a special tag to issues in progress after a couple of days. Tags are visible on the board, so it would be a good indication. And you can also use tags in reports or searches, which can be quite handy as well.